# Does this diagram successfully construct a Kepler triangle?

Tags: geometry

Assuming the starting circle is a unit circle with radius $1$, does this successfully create a Kepler triangle? The legs are $1$ (radius of unit circle), and $\phi$ (radius of circle equal to Odom construction length), leaving the hypotenuse to be $\phi^2$.

[image]

Some references

- Wikipedia ["Kepler triangle"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_triangle)
- Wikipedia ["George Phillips Odom, Jr."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Phillips_Odom_Jr.), noting Odom's construction of the golden ratio by extending an equilateral triangle's midpoint segment to its circumcircle.

---

I’m new to this, I just find it interesting. Sorry if I’m not providing the proper amount of info for my question to make sense.

Comment: You provide diagram without explanation of the steps!

Comment: The side-lengths of a Kepler triangle are in the proportion $1:\sqrt{\phi}:\phi$, not $1:\phi:\phi^2$. (The latter is the proportion of the areas of the squares erected upon the sides of the triangle.)